# how to assign ExecuteStoreCommand result to a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework, I am trying to bind the gridview with the stored procedure I write as follows

```
var ietsParameter = new SqlParameter("@ID", 1000);
grdStoreProc.DataSource = entities.ExecuteStoreCommand("selectData2 @ID", ietsParameter);
grdStoreProc.DataBind();
```

But I am getting an exception

> Data source is an invalid type. It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

Can someone tell me any alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the type of `entities`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecuteStoreCommand` is used to execute a command to the database with an `int` return type that tells how much rows were affected.

You should use `ExecuteStoreQuery` instead.

[Check this link from samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd487208%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks it worked, so when inserting can I use `ExecuteStoreCommand `

Comment: Exactly, `ExecuteStoreCommand` is for Insert, Update and Delete